# How can I get the directory two levels up in a path in Perl?

Tags: perl

How to go two directories up from an environment variable in perl?

```
sub do_file_tracing {
  my var = "$ENV{IMPORTANT_DIR}";

}
```

I want to create a file at `long/path/to/the/important_dir` `long/path/to/the/important_dir/../../` , that is at `long/path/to/`

Comment: See [File::Basename::dirname()](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Basename) and the `parent()` method in [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#parent)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#parent). For example:

```
use Path::Tiny;
my $dir = path($ENV{IMPORTANT_DIR})->parent(2);
```

Answer (score 3):

```perl
my $dir_qfn = "$ENV{IMPORTANT_DIR}/../..";
```